# Find the Runner Up Score

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to programming and I have ran into a problem while solving this HackerRank problem.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen
My code is working fine but I'm not able to obtain the desired output.

```
student_marks = {}
lsit_name = []
lsit_marks = []
N = int(input())

for _ in range(N):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    student_marks[name] = [score]
    lsit_marks.append(score)
    lsit_name.append(name)

final = []

for i in range(len(student_marks)):
    if lsit_marks[i] < max(lsit_marks):
        final.append(lsit_marks[i])
print(lsit_name[lsit_marks.index(max(final))])


final_1 = []

for i in range(len(final)):
    if final[i] < max(final):
        final_1.append(final[i])

print(lsit_name[lsit_marks.index(max(final_1))])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go is by using a dictionary to keep the grades as its keys. By ordering the list accordingly, you can introduce the key-values pairs in the dictionary so that when printing later, you get the desired output.

This takes advantage from the fact that as for Python 3.6, the dictionaries maintain insertion order. If you are running a previous Python version, you will want to use a `OrderedDict` object, from the `collections` module, instead.

```
students = [[input(), float(input())] for _ in range(int(input()))]
d = dict()
for name, grades in sorted(students, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])):
    d.setdefault(grades, []).append(name)
print(*d[list(d.keys())[1]], sep='\n')
```

So, for the following input:

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

You will get the following output:

```
Berry
Harry
```